# What is the meaning of `ATTR{stat}==“ ...”` on udev attributes?

Tags: udev, devices, usb-device

I was studying about the activity/change while copy pasting file in USB. Seems like the **stat** attribute gets changed on every action on USB drive. So what does each value of these stat denotes?

Command used:

> udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=sdb1

A Part of output:

```
ATTRS{stat}=="     263    14879    17884     1145      559      122   126280
      10082        0     2892     9348        0        0        0        0"
```

What are the meaning of each values of `ATTRS{stat}`? Any links to documentation will also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a block device, the `stat` `udev` attribute shows the device’s statistics, which can also be seen in the corresponding entry under `/sys/devices` (`udevadm info` will show the full path) and under `/sys/block` (`/sys/block/sdb/sdb1/stat` in your example).

The entries can be seen in [`block/genhd.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9.6/source/block/genhd.c#L1292) and are [documented in the kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/block/stat.html); they are, in order:

- number of read I/Os processed
- number of read I/Os merged with in-queue I/O
- number of sectors read
- total wait time for read requests (in milliseconds)
- number of write I/Os processed
- number of write I/Os merged with in-queue I/O
- number of sectors written
- total wait time for write requests (in milliseconds)
- number of I/Os currently in flight
- total time this block device has been active (in milliseconds)
- total wait time for all requests (in milliseconds)
- number of discard I/Os processed
- number of discard I/Os merged with in-queue I/O
- number of sectors discarded
- total wait time for discard requests (in milliseconds)
- number of flush I/Os processed
- total wait time for flush requests (in milliseconds)

Comment: Thank you @Stephen for the answer. Another thing, Is there a way to determine how many MB of data is transferred to USB using `udev` or so?

Comment: I don’t know off-hand, it would be worth asking a separate question.